# The background image is not displayed in footer

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am working on a wordpress site http://cardinalmma.com/wordpress/. You can see a background image which is of tiles. But that image is not appear as background in footer.
Here is the home template

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Home template
*/
include('header.php'); ?>

<div id="background">


        <div id="home_primary">
            <div id="content" role="main">


<div id="social_icons">
<div id="facebook">
</div>
<div id="twitter">
</div>
<div id="linkedin">
</div>
<div id="rss">
</div>

</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>  

                <div id="text_back">
                <div id="brad">
                </div>

                <div id="text">

                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>
                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?></div> 

                <div id="twitter_feed">
                </div>
                </div>

<div id="bottom">
</div>



</div><!-- #content -->
        </div><!-- #primary -->




<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Here is the footer

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the footer.
 *
 * Contains the closing of the id=main div and all content after
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Eleven
 * @since Twenty Eleven 1.0
 */
?>





            <?php
                /* A sidebar in the footer? Yep. You can can customize
                 * your footer with three columns of widgets.
                 */
                if ( ! is_404() )
                    get_sidebar( 'footer' );
            ?>




                <div id="footer">
                <div id="wrap" style="width:1000px;margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;">


                <div id="bottomMenu">
                 <div align="center" style="font-family: Calibri;font-size: 25px;text-transform: uppercase;color: #e61e25;">Navigate</div>

                <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'secondary' ) ); ?>
                </div>
                <div id="contacts">
                <div align="center" style="font-family: Calibri;font-size: 25px;text-transform: uppercase;color: #e61e25;">Contacts</div>
                </div>


                <div id="copyright">
                2013 © – <a href="http://cardinalmma.com" target="_blank">cardinalmma.com</a> – All Rights Reserved </div>






                </div>


                </div>
            </div>

</div><!-- #page -->

<?php wp_footer(); ?>





</div>
</body>
</html>
```

css is large so i am not attaching.

Can anyone please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are floating the elements in the footer - when floating elements, they are taken out of the document flow, causing the parent to collapse.

To prevent this, you can either use the [micro-clearfix method](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/):

```
#footer:before,
#footer:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

#footer:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

… or use `overflow: hidden;` on the parent (which is simpler, but may not be applicable in all situations):

```
#footer {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```